# How do I access custom fields in Acumatica C#

Tags: c#, acumatica

I'm attempting to update a custom field in GLTran. On the Account Details screen I have a button that, when clicked, should update a custom field for each selected transaction. I am unable to access the custom field in order to update it. Here's my most recent iteration of my code:

```
public class AccountByPeriodEnq_Extension:PXGraphExtension<AccountByPeriodEnq>
{
    public PXAction<AccountByPeriodFilter> recon;

    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Reconcile")]
    protected void Recon()
    {
        PXCache gltran = Base.Caches[typeof(GLTran)];
        foreach (GLTran tran in gltran.Updated)
        {
            var GLTranEx = tran.GetExtension<GLTranExt>(); 
            //                                 ^^^^
            //This is giving "The type or namespace name "GLTranExt" could not be found

            GLTranEx.UsrRecon = true;                
        }
    }
}
```

Please go easy on me as this is my first attempt at Acumatica customization.

Comment: add `using NAMESPACE;` where NAMESPACE is the namespace of  your GLTranExt dac extension

Comment: The namespaces are the same. There must be something jacked up in my VS environment. I rebooted my server to install some updates and when it came back up this started working in Acumatica even though I'm still getting the error message in VS. When I attach the debugger to IIS, it passes right over it with no issues.

Comment: Errors in VS is probably due to runtime types that can't be checked by static analysis of intellisense, usually happens on DAC extensions. You can discard those as non-errors.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it looks like the namespace of type GLTranExt is not accessible from the namespace of type AccountByPeriodEnq_Extension. You could put both types in the same namespace or with 'using' directive you could declare the namespace.

On second look, it could be that you have some naming mismatch as I see in some place you use:

```
GLTranEx
```

And in others:

```
GLTranExt
```

When using Customization Project Editor you can check the namespace of the DAC extension with VIEW SOURCE button:
[image]

If you have the DAC extension as a code file, namespace is in the source code:

```
namespace PX.Objects.GL
{
  public class GLTranExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.GL.GLTran>
  {
  }
}
```

As you can see by default extension of GLTran goes into namespace PX.Objects.GL
In your code, I would expect a 'using' directive on that namespace:

```
using PX.Objects.GL;

public class AccountByPeriodEnq_Extension:PXGraphExtension<AccountByPeriodEnq>
{
}
```

Or put the namespace prefix on the type:

```
PX.Objects.GL.GLTranExt GLTranEx = tran.GetExtension<PX.Objects.GL.GLTranExt>();
```

Comment: I rebooted my server and it appears to be working now. My new problem is it is not saving the value. I select rows, click my button, and the rows update, but if I leave the screen and come back, the values are gone.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the DAC extension? The most obvious thing to check is if UsrRecon is of type PXDBBool instead of PXBool. Types with DB are persisted to database while type without it are unbound (in memory, non persisted).

Comment: Yes, it is PXDBBool