# Set default values when creating contact from lead

Tags: customization, default, acumatica

I added a few custom string fields using NameValuePair in the Lead form (CR301000).  Using the an Action, I create a contact from the lead.  I added the same custom fields to my Contact form (CR302000).  How can I get the custom values from my lead to my new contact?  I tried using the following:

[PXFormula(typeof(Selector<CRLead.contactID, ContactExtNV.usrCROnline>))]

I'm going to have the same issue when I create an account from the lead.  Is there a better way to do this instead of using PXFormula?

Answer (score 1):

The `Selector` parameter for the `PXFormula` attribute looks like this:
**Selector** –> `Selector<KeyField, ForeignOperand>`
`KeyField`-> The key field to which the `PXSelector` attribute should be attached.
`ForeignOperand`-> The expression that is calculated for the data record currently referenced by `PXSelector`.

That is, in your case it turns out like this:

```
 [PXFormula(typeof(Selector<Contact.contactID, CRLeadExt.usrCROnline>))]
 public string UsrCROnline { get; set; }
```

[Adding namespace in the source code using Customization Project Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51368453/7198805)

Comment: Unfortunately, I get an error when I try and compile or publish the project.  The error message includes: error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CRLeadExt' could not be found

Comment: Where you are developing your customization on Customization Project Editor or Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm using the Customization Project Editor

Comment: check your namespaces, I think you didn't add the namespace for the 'CRLeadExt'

Comment: I did not add that namespace and it might not be included by default.  But I don't know how I would do that using the project editor.

Comment: I changed my answer and add the link which is described namespace adding process